# Using Jetty to serve a web application

Tags: apache, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using Jetty for the first time to deploy a GWT web app connecting to a Restlet API and I am trying to understand the best way to use it.

I want to make it embeddable so that I can update config during run-time (allowing me to add new domain names etc).

Our web server currently runs Apache to serve a PHP web app and this will be our first time deploying a GWT app and using Jetty.

Is it possible to use Jetty in parallel with Apache (both serving requests on port 80) and since I am embedding it do I use Apache before it reaches Jetty? So Apache receives request and forwards to Jetty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both server cannot run on same port. But you can run both on same machine. So use a separate port for jetty.

Jetty receives the request through its own port and doesn't depend on other server.